# Embed Sender in discord.py, with three custom arguments

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a simple embed sender, that has the parts of: Title, Description and Footer.

Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx, *, title, desc, footer):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{title}", description=f"{desc}", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{footer}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The error that I having is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ryzen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: embed() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'desc' and 'footer'
```

Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In commands `*` will get every thing after it, using variables will make it a single word.

Using the `*` to get all the data as one variable. You must split the data somehow i did it here using `-` which will make a list of stings indices are commented in the code.

Use it like this `{prefix}embed title here - desc here - footer here`

```py
@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx, *, data):
    data = data.split('-')  # title = 0, desc = 1, footer=2
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"{data[0]}", description=f"{data[1]}", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{data[2]}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass long string to your variable using quotes:

```py
async def embed(ctx, title, desc, footer):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=desc, color=0x00ff00)
    embed.set_footer(text=footer)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Usage: `{prefix}embed "title here" "desc here" "footer here"`

Comment: Thank u bro . You helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one argument after the `*`, and all remaining data will be passed in this one argument.

For example: `async def embed(ctx, title, desc, *, footer)`

If you pass the following command: `!embed Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`

You will get variables that look like:

```
title = "Lorem"
desc = "ipsum"
footer = "dolor sit amet"
```